# Bold User name text on login screen

Tags: 18.04, themes, login-screen

In 18.04, during the first login, my user name appears in bold text. I need to click on it to enter the password. Is it possible to remove `bold` and make the user name appears as `normal` text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In defualt Ubuntu 18.04, the .css file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` is the one need to edit..

open the file with below command

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

go to line number around 1726 and find the below content,

```
.login-dialog-username,
.user-widget-label {
  color: #eeeeec;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px; }
```

change the `font-weight: bold;` to `font-weight: normal;`

save the file, close and reboot to see the change in effect..

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm :)